# How to access env variables in React with ansible

Tags: reactjs, docker, ansible, devops

I have docker container with a react app and it used in docker hub registry, after that my ansible script deploys it to server. I need to pass env variables to react app.

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_container_module.html#parameter-env

Comment: I tried it, it's not works for me, react seems can read env variables only from .env file

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the values in `process.env` or `.env.local` before creating the build using react's webpack.

Comment: yep, but I guess then my env variables will be in docker image and eventually in dockerhub registry, that means, some secrets will be in dockerhub registry, I think it isn't good. I need to pass env variables in ansible to react app when container starts

Comment: then every time you start your container you have to build react project

Comment: I can do something like this```CMD envsubst 'REACT_APP_SOME_SECRET_VAR=$APP_DOMAIN' < /.env.tmpl > /.env && server -p 3000 -s .```, so .env would be generated during runtime, but I have to put every var to envsubst :(

Comment: try and use this solution until you find any better one :(